# If $(\Omega,A)$ is a measurable space and $R$ is a generator of $A$, then any $A$-measurable function can be approximated by $R$-measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ be a measureable space
- $\mathcal R\subseteq 2^\Omega$ with $\sigma(\mathcal R)=\mathcal A$

Can we approximate a $\mathcal A$-measurable function $X:\Omega\to\overline{\mathbb R}$ by functions of the form $\sum_{i=1}^kx_i1_{R_i}$ with $k\in\mathbb N$, $x_1,\ldots,x_k\in\mathbb R$ and $R_1,\ldots,R_k\in\mathcal R$?

We clearly know that this is true for $\mathcal R=\mathcal A$.

> Can we show that such an approximation is possible in the sense of pointwise convergence?

Maybe it's possible, if we assume that $\mathcal R$ is a ring or an algebra ...

Comment: I'm not sure but it should be true. To show it, it's sufficient to show that for any $A\in\mathcal{A}$ you can approximate $1_A$ by a finite sum $\sum_{i=1}^k 1_{R_i}$ with $R_i\in\mathcal{R}$. I think you can show that the collection of sets which can be arbitrarily approximated in this way form a Dynkin system, and clearly $\mathcal{R}$ is contained in such collection, so by Dynkin lemma you can conclude.

Comment: @Lucio, I feel similarly.  Nonetheless, it's not obvious that $\Omega$ would be in the family, which is a necessary condition for a Dynkin system.

Comment: It's true. Use the monotone class theorem for functions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem

Comment: @VeridianDynamics Are you sure? Even without the additional assumption $\Omega\in\mathcal R$?

Comment: @Lucio I guess you mean the following: $$\mathcal H:=\left\{H:Ω→ℝ\mid\exists(H_n)_{n∈ℕ}⊆\mathcal E(\mathcal R)\text{ with }H_n\xrightarrow{n→∞}H\right\}$$ ($\mathcal E(\mathcal R)$ denotes the linear span of $\left\{1_R:R∈\mathcal R\right\}$) is a $\mathbb R$-vector space. And we want to show that $$\mathcal D:=\left\{A∈σ(\mathcal R):1_A∈\mathcal H\right\}$$ is a Dynkin-System. Please assume $Ω∈\mathcal R$ and hence $Ω∈\mathcal D$. Moreover, it's clear that $B\setminus A∈\mathcal D$ for all $A,B∈\mathcal D$ with $A⊆ B$.

Comment: @fourierwho My problem is to show that $$A:=\biguplus_{n∈ℕ}A_n∈\mathcal D$$ for all disjoint $(A_n)_{n∈ℕ}⊆\mathcal D$. Let $$B_n:=\sum_{i=1}^nA_i\;\;\;\text{for }n∈ℕ\;.$$ Then, $$1_{B_n}=\sum_{i=1}^n1_{A_i}\in\mathcal H\;\;\;\text{for all }n∈ℕ$$ and $$1_{B_n}\xrightarrow{n→∞}1_A\;.$$ However, I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer; if I have time I will extend it later if something more comes up. Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measurable space and let $\mathcal{R}$ be a basis of $\mathcal{A}$ such that $\Omega\in\mathcal{R}$. I'll show that any integrable $\mathcal{A}$-measurable function can be approximated in the $L^1$ norm by functions of the form above, which also implies, up to a subsequence, that there is also $\mu$-a.e. pointwise convergence (however I don't know if we can obtain pointwise convergence $\textit{everywhere}$). To do that, it's sufficient to show that such approximation holds for $1_A$ with $A\in\mathcal{A}$ (because you can approximate integrable functions by simple functions which are finite combinations of these functions). Consider the following class of sets:
$$ \mathcal{H}=\big\{A\in\mathcal{A}\ \vert \forall \varepsilon >0\ \exists\ B_\varepsilon, C_\varepsilon \in\mathcal{R} \text{ s.t. } B_\varepsilon\subset A\subset C_\varepsilon \text{ and } \mu(A-B_\varepsilon)\leq\varepsilon, \mu(C_\varepsilon-A)\leq\varepsilon\big\}$$
It's clear that $\mathcal{R}\subset \mathcal{H}$, so if we show that $\mathcal{H}$ is a Dynkin system, by Dynkin lemma we can conclude (by the way, this tells you that not only we can approximate $A$, but we can do it from the inside or from the outside as we prefer, which implies that $1_A$ can be approximated by a monotone sequence $1_{R_i}$ and so the result can be extended to approximating monotonically integrable functions).

We assumed $\Omega\in\mathcal{R}$, so $\Omega\in\mathcal{H}$; the best way to see that $A_1, A_2\in\mathcal{H}$ with $A_2\subset A_1$ implies $A_1\setminus A_2\in\mathcal{H}$ is to draw a picture (but it can be also written formally, you can check). Now let $A_n\in \mathcal{H}$, $\varepsilon>0$ fixed. Then there exist $B_n\in\mathcal{R}$ s.t. $B_n\subset A_n$ and $\mu(A_n\setminus B_n)\leq \varepsilon 2^{-n}$. Therefore $\cup_n B_n \subset \cup_n A_n$ and using the fact that $\cup_n A_n \setminus \cup_n B_n \subset \cup_n (A_n\setminus B_n)$ we get 
$$ \mu \Big( \bigcup_n A_n \setminus \bigcup_n B_n\Big) \leq \mu \Big(\bigcup_n (A_n\setminus B_n) \Big)\leq \sum_n \mu(A_n\setminus B_n) \leq \sum_n \varepsilon 2^{-n} = \varepsilon$$
which implies that $\cup_n A_n$ can be approximated from the inside; the proof for the outside is similar and so we can conclude that $\cup_n A_n\in\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ is a Dynkin system.

If we don't assume $\Omega\in\mathcal{R}$, counterexamples can be found. Take for example a measurable set $A$ s.t. $\mu(A)=1/2\mu(\Omega)$, consider $\mathcal{R}=\{ A\}$, and $\mathcal{A}=\sigma(\mathcal{R})=\{\emptyset, A, A^c, \Omega\}$. Then $\mathcal{R}$ is a basis of $\mathcal{A}$, but $1_\Omega$ cannot be approximated by $1_A$.

Regarding the problem of approximation in convergence pointwise everywhere, or the case of a measurable space without a measure assigned on it, I don't have an answer (however the counterexample above with slight modifications still works well without a measure, so the condition $\Omega\in\mathcal{R}$ is probably necessary).